# How to add or overload function to vector

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I want to make my coding a bit easier by creating an operator to my vector.

I have a class `Voxelgrid`:

```
class Voxelgrid {
    struct Voxel{
        float dist;
        float weight;
        };
    vector<Voxel> grid;
    int RESOLUTION;
};
```

Now the thing is that I want to acces and write to these Voxels quite a lot and I will access them by using the indexing:

```
grid[i + j*RESOLUTION + k*RESOLUTION*RESOLUTION].distance
```

for example.

Is it possible to write an operator so that I can instead write

```
grid(i,j,k).distance
```

instead.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to write is on a `voxelgrid` instead of a the grid member ? That is `voxelgrid(i,j,k).distance` or  `voxelgrid[i,j,k].distance` (both are possible.

Comment: `s/distance/dist/`, presumably. And it looks like you use `grid` for a `Voxelgrid` instance in the examples, but this is confusing as the vector member is also called `grid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```
class Voxelgrid 
{
public:
   const Voxel & operator []( std::vector<Voxel>::size_type i ) const
   {
      return grid[i];
   }
//...
};
```

Or you can define a member function

```
class Voxelgrid 
{
public:
   const Voxel & GetVoxel( size_type i, size_type j, size_type k ) const
   {
      return grid[i + j*RESOLUTION + k*RESOLUTION*RESOLUTION];
   }
//...
};
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the '&' in const Voxel & GetVoxel/operator  mean?

Comment: @Erik: Read the chapter in your C++ book about references. Actually, read the whole book.

Comment: @Erik it mwans a constant reference to an element of the vector. So you may applied methods of the class that declared as const.

Comment: Thank you Vlad, I am trying to improve my knowledge in C++ by reimplementing some projects I have done in a different way.